# Why does useState get shared across routes with different props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have an app that has two tabs "Apple" and "Banana". Each tab has a counter that is implemented with `useState`.

```js
const Tab = ({ name, children = [] }) => {
  const id = uuid();
  const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0);

  const onClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCount(c => c + 1);
  };

  const style = {
    background: "cyan",
    margin: "1em",
  };

  return (
    <section style={style}>
      <h2>{name} Tab</h2>
      <p>Render ID: {id}</p>
      <p>Counter: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={onClick}>+1</button>
      {children}
    </section>
  );
};
```

What is confusing is that the counter state is shared between both tabs!

If I increment the counter on one tab and then switch to the other tab, the counter has changed there too.

Why is this?

---

Here is my complete app:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import { HashRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Tab = ({ name, children = [] }) => {
  const id = uuid();
  const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0);

  const onClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCount(c => c + 1);
  };

  const style = {
    background: "cyan",
    margin: "1em",
  };

  return (
    <section style={style}>
      <h2>{name} Tab</h2>
      <p>Render ID: {id}</p>
      <p>Counter: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={onClick}>+1</button>
      {children}
    </section>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const id = uuid();

  return (
    <Router>
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
      <p>Render ID: {id}</p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/apple">Apple</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/banana">Banana</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/apple"
          exact={true}
          render={() => {
            return <Tab name="Apple" />;
          }}
        />
        <Route
          path="/banana"
          exact={true}
          render={() => {
            return <Tab name="Banana" />;
          }}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(<App />);
```

---

Versions:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router": "5.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
```

Comment: What version react-router-dom?

Comment: @Adam added to question. it's a slightly old version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with the way [`Switch` works in react-router-dom](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v5.3.4/packages/react-router/modules/Switch.js#L23-L26)

Ultimately, your tree of components remains identical, even when you switch routes.

It's always a Router -> Switch -> Route -> Tab

Because of the way Switch works, React never "mounts" a new component, it just reuses the old tree, because it can.

I've run into this exact issue before, the fix is to add a key somewhere, like on the `Tab` or the `Route`. I usually add it to the `Route` because it makes more sense in my mind:

```
      <Switch>
        <Route
          key={'apple'}
          path="/apple"
          exact={true}
          render={() => {
            return <Tab name="Apple" />;
          }}
        />
        <Route
          key={'banana'}
          path="/banana"
          exact={true}
          render={() => {
            return <Tab name="Banana" />;
          }}
        />
      </Switch>
```

Check this stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gj5mcv?file=src/App.js

Of course, your state gets reset in each tab when they get unmounted, which may or may not be desirable. But the solution to that, of course (if it's a problem for you), is, as usual, to lift state up.

Comment: It works! What a strange bug

Comment: @sdgfsdh - it's not a bug, it's deliberate behaviour that I (and some other people) find unintuitive

Comment: my usage of it resulted in a bug

Comment: @sdgfsdh added this link to my answer, thought you might find it interesting: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v5.3.4/packages/react-router/modules/Switch.js#L23-L26

Comment: IMO it makes more sense to place the React key on the `Tab` component so it is ***overtly*** clear what React will do with the `Tab` component when the key changes, but use what makes the most sense to you and is easy to read and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Adam has a great explanation and answer for what is happening here and that it  is an optimization to not tear down and remount the same React component simply because the URL path changed. Using a React key will certainly solve this by ***forcing*** React to remount the `Tab` component and thus "reset" the `count` state.

I'd suggest another method that keeps the routed component mounted and simply resets the `count` state when the `name` prop changes from `"apple"` to `"banana"` and vise-versa.

```
const Tab = ({ name, children = [] }) => {
  const id = uuid();
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(0); // <-- reset to 0 when name prop updates
  }, [name, setCount]);

  const onClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCount(c => c + 1);
  };

  const style = {
    background: "cyan",
    margin: "1em",
  };

  return (
    <section style={style}>
      <h2>{name} Tab</h2>
      <p>Render ID: {id}</p>
      <p>Counter: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={onClick}>+1</button>
      {children}
    </section>
  );
};
```

This will keep the RRD optimization working for you instead of against you.

If you didn't have a passed prop like `name` to take a cue from, then `location.pathname` could be used. Note that this does couple some internal component logic to external details.

Example:

```js
const { pathname } = useLocation();
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  setCount(0);
}, [pathname, setCount]);
```

Comment: While it's true the key property removes a potential performance optimization (note: never prematurely optimize) that RRD gives you, my gripe with this code is that it makes `Tab` less simple to reason about. It brings the knowledge of what's going on outside of `Tab` and what it's being rendered by and how it's being rendered inside of `Tab`. Coupling it (ever so slightly, in this particular example, but by the time 4 other devs have added their own state and useEffects.....) with context - not the React context but the context the developer must have who reads it.

Comment: @Adam Well, I personally find seeing the dependency explicitly spelled out ***in*** the component to be more intuitive and less prone to issue if I happen to forget to specify a React key externally. Let's hope most dev teams end up with at least two devs that think like the both/either of us to at least keep these quirks in mind, and that they do quality code reviews. 